# How I can make and use custom url in cakephp

Tags: cakephp, routes

I am using cakephp 2.4.1, I want make following url for my project. how is it possible?

```
http://example.com/privew/Homepage?=true
```

or

`http://example.com/privew?=true` . I tried it like this

```
Router::connect('/privew/*',array('controller'=>'Admin','action'=>'privew'));
```

But it is not helping. Anybody knows how to do it

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the extra slash before * like:

```
Router::connect('/privew*',array('controller'=>'Admin','action'=>'privew'));
```

Also I don't know if you have controller Admin, it should be 'admins' though and it should be lowercase.

Comment: I have AdminController and I am used to write in link as `'controller'=>'Admin'`

Comment: Well, if the controller file is `AdminController.php`, then it can be either `Admin` or `admin`.

Answer (score 0):

```
Router::url(array(
'controller' => 'posts',
'action' => 'index',
'?' => array('page' => 1),
'#' => 'top'
```

));

// will generate a URL like.
/posts/index?page=1#top

So you can try like this

Refer this for more info
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html#Router::connectNamed